# How to get the perspective list programatically in Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing an Eclipse plugin where the user can create perspectives from scratch. The user must enter a name for the perspective among other things and I need to check if the name already exists, so I need to read the information about the perspectives. I also need to add the perspective to the list programatically.

Do you know which class is related with the perspectives (not the UI)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IPerspectiveRegistry perspectives = PlatformUI.getWorkbench ().getPerspectiveRegistry ();
if (perspectives.findPerspectiveWithLabel (name) != null){
    //Error
}
```